# Не работает функция запроса с параметром

Tags: php, база-данных, mysqli

Здраствуйте! Пишу функцию которая будет выполнять запрос к базе но с параметром, не пойму почему то выбивает ошибку.

> Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: mysqli_stmt::execute()
> expects exactly 0 arguments, 1 given in
> C:\OpenServer\domains\labs\db.php:38 Stack trace: #0
> C:\OpenServer\domains-labs\db.php(38): mysqli_stmt->execute() #1
> C:\OpenServer\domains\labs\functions.php(55):
> DB->executePrepareQuery() #2
> C:\OpenServer\domains\labs\index.php(140):
> functions->getGoodsInCategory() #3 {main} thrown in
> C:\OpenServer\domains\labs\db.php on line 38

файлы:
db.php

```
function executePrepareQuery($sql, $array_param){
        $data = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
        $data->execute($array_param);
        return $data;
}
```

function.php

```
public function getGoodsInCategory($id_category){
$data = $this->db->executePrepareQuery("SELECT good.name, good.description, good.general_number, good.price 
    FROM goods good, category categor 
    WHERE good.id_categories = categor.id_category 
    AND good.id_categories = ?;",[$id_category]);
$goods = null;
while ($current_good = $data->fetch_assoc()) {
$goods[] = $current_good;
}
return $goods;
}
```

Есть простая функция которая без параметров то рабоет. Если просто отправить готовый SQL запрос.

Comment: переводили ошибку? что переводит "expects exactly 0 arguments, 1 given" ?

Comment: ожидает ровно 0 аргументов, задан 1 я то понял что оно переводит, но я так понял проблема  
$data->execute($array_param);
Но в документации написано что public mysqli_stmt::execute(?array $params = null): bool

Comment: покажите полностью что у вас в executePrepareQuery

Comment: Я саму функцию написал вверху!

function executePrepareQuery($sql, $array_param){
        $data = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
        $data->execute($array_param);
        return $data;
}

Comment: Есть предположение, что массив можно добавлять начиная с версии php8. для 5,7 смотрю доки и везде написано `execute()`. то есть надо prepare - bind_param - exectute()

Comment: Похоже я прав https://stackoverflow.com/a/71178410/6104996  (правда почему-то чел написал про 8.1)

Answer (score 0):

Судя по документации: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.execute.php#refsect1-mysqli-stmt.execute-changelog

```
Версия  Описание
8.1.0   Добавлен необязательный параметр params.
```

То есть если версия *PHP* ниже 8.1, то надо использовать связку

```
"prepare" -> "bind_param" -> "execute()" (без параметров)
```

в ином случаем можно уже просто

```
"prepare" -> "execute($array)"
```

Comment: "prepare" -> "bind_param" -> "execute()" (без параметров). А как же тогда параметр передать? Если я его не вписываю. Ну точнее я знаю связку bind_params но там нужно указывать тип параметра, а если у меня каждый раз разный то int то string параметр

Comment: .......bind_param

Comment: Записал я
`$data->bind_param("i",$array_param);  $data->execute();`
Но это получаеться только для int будет функция работать. И теперь новая ошибка Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_assoc() в этой функции  `public function getGoodsInCategory($id_category)`

Comment: @СергейГуртовой, потому что нужно биндить не массив, а элементы массива (т.е. циклом каждый элемент биндить в запрос)

Comment: А можна пожалуйста в виде кода... я вот глянут у меня стояла 8.0 версия.. Значит через бинд.. ок... Я послушал вас и если правильно понял что запил так  $data->bind_param("i",$array_param[0]); так как у меня всего один элемент в массиве. Но результат тот же.

Comment: Вийшло таким чином вивести..
` function executePrepareQuery($sql, $array_param){
            $data = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
            $data->execute($array_param);
        return $data->get_result();
    }`